# Adding a standalone help page for an R package, using roxygen

Tags: r, r-package, roxygen2

Some R packages that don't use roxygen have special help pages in their documentation, where the help page doesn't correspond to any function but rather documents overall features of the package. This is a nice alternative to using vignettes.

An example is the 'survey' package has special documentation pages for package options. For example, when the user loads the 'survey' package and types `?surveyoptions`, they get a help page in RStudio or whatever IDE they're using. And in the PDF manual on CRAN, there's a page of the manual for this item.

> [image]

The 'survey' package does this using an '.Rd' file without any help from 'roxygen2'. Here's the link to the ".Rd" file that the package author manually created.

> https://github.com/cran/survey/blob/master/man/surveyoptions.Rd

I'd like to do the same thing for my package, but using 'roxygen2' to help me out. Is that possible?

Comment: have you tried something like [this](https://github.com/cran/igraph/blob/master/R/igraph-package.R#L28:L36)? at the end you would put NULL instead of a function

Comment: That works great. If you post an answer with this approach (a couple lines of example code), I'm happy to accept it as the answer.

Comment: https://r-pkgs.org/man.html#sec-man-package-doc is a good reference

Comment: Possible alternative (I don't use roxygen here, so I don't know if it's capable) would be to create a "vignette" instead of a man page.

Comment: Thanks, Carl, I appreciate the good suggestion. The reason I asked about a help page specifically is that it's more easily accessed from within an IDE. Some content is a better fit for a vignette, some content is better for a help page.